# JQuery via JSDom isn't a functor giving TypeError

Tags: jquery, node.js, mocha.js, jsdom, io.js

With IO.js 1.3.0 using JSDOM 4.0.1 with Mocha 2.0.1 and jquery 2.1.1 on Windows

The following code:

```
 var chai = require('chai');
 var jsdom = require('jsdom');

describe('JSDOM', function () {
var $;

beforeEach(function () {
    global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<html><body><section id="banner"></section></body></html>');
    global.window = global.document.defaultView;
    global.navigator = global.window.navigator;

    $ = global.jQuery = require('jquery')(global.window);
})

it('Using jquery', function () {
    var dom = $("#banner");
});
});
```

errors out with **TypeError: object is not a function** when trying to use the JQuery selector as a functor (i.e. $(...)).  Anybody else run into this and have a workaround?

Comment: Until I find the root cause of why jquery isn't initializing properly (as a required module) I have pulled it in as source (i.e. via **fs**) and used **jsdom.env** instead (i.e. jsdom.env({html: <frag>, src: [jquery], done: function(erros, window) { // here init my test case then done(); }});

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are setting set `global.window` and `global.document`. jQuery is checking for those to find out if it is running in a browser.

This causes `require('jquery')(global.window)` to wrap the window instead of running the jquery factory function, just like `$(window)` would.

Comment: Thanks @JoWie, took away the **global.window** argument to the require of jquery and it works.